# Catel project slow to build

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I am creating very simple WPF .NET4 project using Catel Project Template in VS2013. I am using pre-release builds. As per readme I am adding Catel.Extensions.Controls. Immidiately I am trying to build and get error on RegisterDebugListener(), which I comment out. However, my main issue is that simple blank demo  (without any controls) is taking over 20sec to compile? Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: 20 seconds is a long time to compile. Is this every time or is it only the first time? And are you using Catel.Fody as well?

Comment: Hi, it is happening every time... and I dont use Catel.Fody. It is just empty Catel project without any controls whatsover

Comment: Have you tried to check out the output window to see timings?

Comment: Yes I did and see that the main dealy is related to : The thread 0x4ddc has exited with code 259 (0x103).

Comment: Please try with diagnostic output of msbuild to gather more details.

Comment: As alternative I tried to use stable release (which is 3.9) and everything just works:)... Do you suggest to use this one? if you need a demo project with pre-released I can send it to you... thanks...

Comment: Please do in the official issue tracker. Then I can check it out, but don't see slow builds myself.